# How to add a Jar task to a configuration in a dependencies block?

Tags: gradle

Consider the following build.gradle script:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

sourceSets {
    common
    admin
    importer
}

dependencies {  
    commonCompile 'org.hibernate:hibernate:3.5.4-Final'
    commonCompile 'org.springframework:spring-hibernate3:2.0.8'

    adminCompile // How to add dependency on commonJar task here?
    adminCompile ...

    importerCompile // How to add dependency on commonJar task here?
    importerCompile ...
}

task commonJar(type: Jar) {
    from sourceSets.common.output
}

task adminWar(type: War) {  
    classpath sourceSets.admin.output
    classpath configurations.adminCompile
    ...
}

task importerWar(type: War) {   
    classpath sourceSets.importer.output
    classpath configurations.importerCompile
    ...
}
```

I want to add a dependency to to `adminWar` and `importerWar`, such that  commonJar will generate a Jar if it doesn't exist, and `adminWar` and `importerWar` will contain that .jar along with the .jar's dependencies on their classpath.  I can not for the life of me figure out how to do this, but feel like it is something simple.

Thank you.